# Python type hint for iterable container with hashed storage of elements (so constant-time membership test)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

Recently I've been finding myself trying to type-hint function arguments that should be iterable containers with hashed storage of elements so that membership test is constant-time on average. Examples include `AbstractSet` (so both `Set` and `FrozenSet`), `Dict` (because the keys have constant time lookup), `KeysView` (I *think* it has constant time lookup but correct me if I'm wrong). Is there one type hint that encompasses all iterable containers with hashed storage of elements?

So far the best I have is something like `Union[KeysView, AbstractSet, Dict]`, but it's ugly and not all-encompassing.

**EDIT**
I've rephrased the question to emphasise **hashed storage of elements** rather than *constant-time membership test*, in response to a comment below.

Comment: There is no formal requirement for any type to support constant time lookups. Even for `set` and `dict` the lookup is only `O(1)` in the best case, it's `O(n)` in the worst case. That doesn't answer your question but it's an important fact to keep in mind if you want to have "runtime complexities for certain operations" as type hints.

Comment: @MSeifert, right, I guess what I meant was a type hint that indicates a container which hashes its elements in order to store them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>If you want to check for hashable containers, you can use `typing.Hashable`.</s> That is not true because `typing.Hashable` applies for all hashable objects and not only containers based on hashing.

You might create your custom type hint:

```
myHashable = Union[KeysView, AbstractSet, Dict]
```

As @MSeifert mentioned though, there is no guarantee of *constant* time lookup.

Comment: I might be mistaken but I thought `Hashable` indicates that it has an `__hash__` method. Not that it's a container based on hashing.

Comment: Ah right, thought it was for containers only but seems not to be the case…